# Random Matrix Question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-matrices

Let $A$ be a $n\times m$ ($n<m$) random matrix with normal i.i.d. entries ($N(0,1)$).

Using the law of large numbers, it readily can be shown that as $n\to\infty$
$$
\frac{1}{n}A^TA\to I_m
$$
where $I_m$ is $m\times m$ identity matrix. Indeed, the $(i,j)$ element of $A^TA$ is given by
$$
\frac{1}{n}[A^TA]_{ij} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{l=1}^nA_{li}A_{lj}\to\delta_{ij}
$$
where $\delta_{ij}$ denoted the delta of Kronecker.

My question is regard the asymptotic behavior of $AA^T$, which is an $n\times n$ matrix with rank $m<n$. Namely, as $n\to\infty$, if we keep a fixed ratio $m/n\to\alpha\in(0,1)$, what can we say about the limit
$$
\frac{1}{n}AA^T\to ?
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This book chapter](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/papers/non-asymptotic-rmt-plain.pdf) can answer your question. Particularly, section 5.3.

Comment: Thanks for this reference. Actually I had skimmed through this work but unfortunately it didn't helped me much. If I am have skipped something, I will be glad if you please tell me so.

Comment: I think even in the first case you mentioned $\frac{1}{n}A^\mathrm{T}A$ doesn't necessarily converge to anything if $m$ and $n$ grow at the same speed. What you said holds only when $m$ is fixed and $n\to \infty$. Something similar happens for the second case. What you can claim though, is that the eigenvalues of those Gram matrices will lie within a fixed interval with high probability.

Comment: Yes, you right. I actually find the following link (page 23)
http://www.flexible-radio.com/sites/default/files/media/1/tutorial_WCNC2012_handout.pdf
where they claim that the diagonal elements converge almost surely to 1 and the off-diagonal converge to zero. But, then it is written that it is not true that $HH^T-I_N\to0$ almost surely. Now, I know that is a very silly and basic question, but why this claim is true? For me it seems obviously (and wrongly) true (maybe I am not understand correctly the definition of a.s. convergence of matrices). Thanks again.

Comment: I think the main issue is that while for any single entry of the Gram matrix you can claim convergence by law of large numbers, the event that **all** entries are within a shrinking interval of $\delta_{ij}$ is rare. Think of "failure" probability being multiplied by something in the order of the number of entries (e.g., in union bound).

Comment: Oh I see...
Thank you again!